# Searching in a CSV for multiple values and get the associated values from it

Tags: bash, awk, grep, csv

I have a **file.csv**

```
"ItemNo","Name","Weight"
"a001","Item a","1.1"
"a002","Item x","1.2"
"a003","Item_4","1.0"
"a004","Item b","1.1"
"a005","Itemb2","2.0"
"a006","a004","2.0"
```

Also I have a few **itemno.csv**

```
"a003"
"a001"
"a004"
```

I am looking for a command to create a list of the "Names" that are associated with the "ItemNo"...

so my **output.csv** should be

```
"Item_4"
"Item a"
"Item b"
```

Can somebody help?

---

each item.no of file.csv in the first column is unique. But there are
a001, a001-b1, a001-b2 and so on.. but if you search for
"a001", "a001-b1", ... everything should be unique again.

I don't need a specific tool.. every useful solution would be ok.
But it would be good if only the first row is searched (assuming the Item.Name of ItemNo "a006" (column 1) is "a004" (column 2)).

---

I tried the **grep command**

```
grep -f itemno.csv file.csv | awk -F, '{print $2}'
```

But **the result** was only the output from the last line:

```
"Item b"
```

---

I tried the **awk command**

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{print $2}' itemno.csv file.csv
```

But **the result** was only the output from the last line:

```
"Item b"
```

### Maybe a loop command is a better idea?

So I tried **this loop**

```
while read -r line; do
    grep "${line}" file.csv | awk -F "," '{print $2}';
done < itemno.csv
```

But there was **no output**...
It seems like after each line there is another **\r**

So I tried **this command**

```
while read line; do
    grep $(printf ${line} | sed 's/\r//g') file.csv | awk -F "," '{print $2}';
done < itemno2.csv
```

with this **itemno2.csv**

```
"a003"
"a001"
"a002"
"a004"
```

And **the output** was:

```
"Item a"
"Item x"
```

Only with this strange loop command I manage to search for the ItemNumbers (and this command is ignoring the first and last line).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is it guaranteed that there is a unique 1-to-1 mapping between item numbers and names (i.e. no name applies to more than one item number, and vice versa)? Do you require the solution to use a specific tool (such as `awk` or `grep`)?

Comment: Were your .csv files created on a dos/windows system? i.e. do they have CRLF line-endings rather than just LF?   if so, then convert them to unix style text files (LF only).  e.g. with `fromdos`.  The itemno.csv file in particular needs to be converted to LF-only line-endings (otherwise the ^M in each itemno.csv line will prevent the matches from working)

Comment: if you don't have fromdos, you can use `sed -i.bak -e 's/\r\n/\n/' itemno.csv file.csv`.  Or just tell awk to use CRLF as the record separator - i.e. add `BEGIN{RS="\r\n"};` to the start of the awk script.  or `BEGIN{RS="\r?\n"};` to work with both dos and windows text files.

Comment: @cas
SORRY... you were right! I don't know how but my itemno.csv had \r on each ending of a line... With a normal itemno.csv awk and grep are working fine.

Comment: Regarding `Maybe a loop command is a better idea?` - no, that'd be extremely slow and fragile, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what my problem was.

The **itemno.csv** was:

```
"a003"\r
"a001"\r
"a004"
```

Without the \r at the end of each line, the command

```
grep -f itemno.csv file.csv | awk -F, '{print $2}'
```

is working better and the **output** is

```
"Item_4"
"Item a"
"Item b"
"a004"
```

---

Without the \r at the end of each line, the command

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{print $2}' itemno.csv file.csv
```

is working better and the **output** is

```
"Item_4"
"Item a"
"Item b"
```

Without the \r at the end of each line, the command the loop command

```
while read line; do
    grep "${line}" file.csv | awk -F "," '{print $2}';
done < itemno.csv
```

gives this **output**

```
"Item_4"
"Item a"
```

Because the `while read` command is not reading the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Your input data is one CSV file and one header-less CSV file.

Starting by adding a header to the header-less CSV file so that we later may refer to the field we're joining with by name as `ItemNo`.  We do this with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) (`mlr`), reading the data as headerless using `--implicit-csv-header` and then employing the `label` sub-command to add the `ItemNo` label to the first column.

```
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header label ItemNo itemno.csv
ItemNo
a003
a001
a004
```

By using `--implicit-csv-header`, Miller internally labels the first field as `1` instead of picking the label from the first line.  The `label` sub-command then changes this to `ItemNo`.

The fact that the data in the output is unquoted does not matter as it doesn't need to be quoted (it contains no embedded delimiters or newlines etc.)  Miller automatically quotes fields that need quoting.

We can then use this in a `join` operation in Miller:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header label ItemNo itemno.csv | mlr --csv join -f file.csv -j ItemNo
ItemNo,Name,Weight
a003,Item_4,1.0
a001,Item a,1.1
a004,Item b,1.1
```

This does a relational "inner join" operation between the `ItemNo` fields of the data in `file.csv` and the data coming from the first `mlr` command in the pipeline.

We may then string on a `cut` operation that extracts the `Name` field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header label ItemNo itemno.csv | mlr --csv join -f file.csv -j ItemNo then cut -f Name
Name
Item_4
Item a
Item b
```

Adding `--headerless-csv-output` we can get header-less CSV output as in the question, and with `--quote-all` we can force Miller to quote all output fields, even though it's not necessary to do so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header label ItemNo itemno.csv | mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --quote-all join -f file.csv -j ItemNo then cut -f Name
"Item_4"
"Item a"
"Item b"
```

Miller does not care whether the input files are DOS or Unix text files, and it's capable of parsing CSV files with complex fields.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/\r$/,"")} NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{print $2}' itemno.csv file.csv
"Item a"
"Item_4"
"Item b"
```

I added that `sub()` at the front since you updated your question to tell us you have DOS line endings.